# DLP Discover job does not start

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dlp

I'm working with the Google Cloud Data Loss Prevention (DLP) API to implement a data discovery job in my project. However, I've encountered a problem where the job I configured does not start as expected. Here's a brief outline of the steps I've followed:

Configured a DLP job trigger for a data discovery job via the Google Cloud Console.
Verified that the trigger is active and the conditions for triggering are met (e.g., new data available).
The job is supposed to start upon meeting the specified conditions, but there's no sign of it beginning or any errors in the logs.

I've also checked the following:

The IAM permissions to ensure the service agent has the roles required to start the job.
The API quotas to ensure I'm not hitting any limits.
That everything is in the same zone

Despite the above checks, the discover job doesn't initiate. Here's what I would like to know:

Are there any common issues or pitfalls that might prevent a DLP discover job from starting?
Is there a way to manually trigger the job for testing purposes?
How can I diagnose the issue further to understand why the job isn't starting?
Any advice or troubleshooting tips from those familiar with the Google Cloud DLP API would be incredibly helpful.

EDIT: This has since posting been resolved but i dont know why.. It started working by itself one week after it stopped working.

Comment: Are you sure the conditions (table names, dataset names) are following the required format? This is one of the major obstacles that prevents the job from running. Please share these details in your question too.

Comment: @FahedSabellioglu Yes, i believe so. But just to clarify, what is the conditions for table names and dataset names? Might be something im missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger inspection jobs by clicking the run now button in the UI of the cloud console.

[image]

But you also said discovery, are you setting up a discovery configuration to get sensitive data profiles, or using inspect job triggers to get findings?

Comment: Im not using inspect job at all because i only want to get sensitive data and as far as i know there is no way to trigger a discover job manually, it should trigger itself when changes happen according to the schedule set up when creating the scan configuration.

Comment: If the question how do you manually force discovery to start, you are right it is automatic. If you create a single table discovery config it's closer to on-demand.